# Android:Switching between 3G and GPRS programmatically?

Tags: android, 3g, gprs, network-security, android-permissions

Is there a way to switch from 3G data to GPRS and back prorammaticaly.assuming there is no wifi involved..

Or is there a way to find out weather phone uses 3g or GPRS?

3G enable and disable is available is wireless&network Communication in phone settings...is there a way to traverse there programmatically to switch 3G to GPRS?

Answer (score 0):

Not without a rooted phone, sorry.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extendedcontrols

this app claims doing it.and has a descent rating